# How to search several words in pkg (FreeBSD)

Tags: freebsd, package-management, pkg

I want to search several words in FreeBSD packages *using* `pkg` [command](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?pkg)

Example, if I want to search all packages with the words "web server" in the description, someone would try this:

```
pkg search web server
```

But it does not work. Neither with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Suspecting you want to search for both words you use `grep`:

```
pkg search web |grep server
```

Based on `pkg` documentation this command should work:

```
pkg -g search "web server"
```

You may add `-i` to make search case insensitive

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1190230)

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, this provide the answer of the question: "How to search several words in pkg". The OP do not mention he/she want to do the entire search **only** in `pkg`. So it is an answer, sample, fast and short! Also it is not required to write "War and Peace" to answer clearly to the question and to provide valuable answer.

Comment: It's a question. I flagged it as low quality answer, feel free to edit and improve it.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, and it provide answer: the example command give to OP the operation he/she search.

Comment: This cicumvents the question using sh commands. But I need to know if there is such capability in `pkg` itself.

Comment: @somenxavier, I update my answer

Comment: @somenxavier if you want a solution using just `pkg`, that should be clearly stated in the question.

Comment: @Destroy666 Edited question

Comment: I run it and I get: `pkg: illegal option -- g` `pkg: Invalid argument provided`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://freshports.org, there is a very nice filtering system to specify what you are looking for.

To do this from the command line, you are looking for the `-S` flag and options.

By default, `pkg` searches on the `pkg-name`. Meaning, if you type `pkg search webserver` it will look for a package with `webserver` in the name. As you probably ran into, this cant find many webservers. Matter of fact, for me, it returned 0 results. The `-S` flag allows us to specify if we wish to search by `pkg-name`, `description`, `comment`, `name`, or `origin`.

Using this, a command of `pkg search -S description "web server"` returns WAY more info. More than I believe you are looking for. This will display the ENTIRE description for every pkg with `web server` in it. So lets say we want to search for all packages that are described as "web servers", but only return the names of those packages. We can apply an additional flag `-L` which can compact it to just the pkg name.

Below is a cleaner option, probably what you are looking for.

`pkg search -S description -L name "web server"`

NOTE: `-S` and `-L` are case-sensitive, refer to `pkg help search` command for more details.

If you run into issues, always always refer to the documentation and man pages!

- FBSD Docs - https://docs.freebsd.org/
- Manpage for pkg - https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?pkg(8)

I hope this helps and informs others as well.